# How to insert a textbox before a button in html and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want the textbox to be inserted before the button, I tried manipulating the insertBefore but couldn't do it.

```js
function addTextBox() {
  const textBox = document.createElement("INPUT");
  textBox.setAttribute("type", "text");
  const field = document.getElementById("field");
  field.appendChild(textBox);

  var plus = document.getElementById("plus");
  field.insertBefore(textBox, plus);

}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
  <form action="Education.html">
    <fieldset id="field">
      <header>Interests Section</header>
      <label for="iname">Interests</label>
      <input type="text" id="iname" placeholder="Descripe your interest..." name="name"><br><br>
      <input type="button" id="plus" onclick="addTextBox()" class="plus" value="+ new interest..." name="plus" />
      <input type="submit" class="hov" style="margin-top:80%" value="Next">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>

<footer>
  Copyright&copy;2022 Rami Joulani
</footer>
```

Comment: `but couldn't do it.`; why not? Did it do something else? Was there an error in your console? Also, you seem to have your syntax for [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) incorrect. The new node comes first.

Comment: It did nothing, if the code is correct maybe visual studio is the problem.

Comment: the new node is the textbox

Comment: Where are you calling your function? Please revise the snippet demo to show the problem.

Comment: You could just write the textbox field in and hide it and then unhide it in your function

Comment: well I noticed that I didn't call the function but I did call it now and nothing changed.

Comment: check the photo, doing the hidden function is not practical, I want it to go down on every click and add a textbox.

Comment: The current code is working fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for informing me, as I said it appears the problem is form visual studio, it worked today.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to stack them then I guess this is how I did it. I append a break in between. I placed a DIV in your field set for it to appear before the buttons in the first place.

```js
function addTextBox() {
  const textBox = document.createElement("INPUT");
  const lbreak = document.createElement("br");
  textBox.setAttribute("type", "text");
  textBox.setAttribute("Placeholder","More interest");
  
  
  const field = document.getElementById("addtextbox");
  
  field.appendChild(textBox);
field.appendChild(lbreak);
  
    }
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
  <form action="Education.html">
    <fieldset id="field">
      <h1>Interests Section</h1>
      <label for="iname">Interests</label>
        <input type="text" id="iname" placeholder="Describe your interest..." name="name"><br><br>
          <div id="addtextbox"></div><br>
        <input type="button" id="plus" onclick="addTextBox()" class="plus" value="+ new interest..." name="plus" >
      <input type="submit" class="hov"  value="Next">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```